# three axis graph in R

Tags: r

I have a question regarding generating a graph in R in a three dimension. Suppose, i have the following data in a csv format file;

```
CPU_Usage Power_Consumption(Watt) Bandwidth  
50        59                      20MB
```

Now i want to represent this on xyz axis where the x-axis represents cpu,y represents power & z represents bandwidth. Then i would want these values to be joined together (by a line) on the three axis graph to form a triangle.There is just a single row in this data. I would appreciate if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with scatterplot3d (among others):

```
library(scatterplot3d)

#first draw the lines of the triangle
#using type="l"  Since we are drawing a
#shape, include the first point twice to
#close the polygon
q <- scatterplot3d(c(50, 0, 0, 50),
  c(0, 59, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 20, 0), 
  xlim=c(0, 60), ylim=c(0, 60), zlim=c(0, 60), type="l", 
  xlab="CPU Usage", ylab="Power Consumption", zlab="Bandwidth",
  box=FALSE)

#now add the points.  scatterplot3d creates a list,
#one element of which is a function that operates
#on the existing chart, q, adding points:
q$points3d(c(50, 0, 0), c(0, 59, 0), c(0, 0, 20))
```

Of course, if you need to do more than one of these, you can pull the points from your data instead of hard-coding them.  I thought hard-coding would make this a bit more readable.